# Is there a way how to address nested properties in AWS DynamoDB for purpose of documentClient.query() call?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-dynamodb

I am currently testing how to design a query from AWS.DynamoDB.DocumentClient query() call that takes params: DocumentClient.QueryInput, which is used for retrieving data collection from a table in DynamoDB.

Query seems to be simple and working fine while working with indexes of type String or Number only. What I am not able to make is an query, that will use a valid index and filter upon an attribute that is nested (see my data structure please).

I am using FilterExpression, where can be defined logic for filtering - and that seems to be working fine in all cases except cases when trying to do filtering on nested attribute.

Current **parameters**, I am feeding query with

```
parameters  {
  TableName: 'myTable',
  ProjectionExpression: 'HashKey, RangeKey, Artist ,#SpecialStatus, Message, Track, Statistics'
  ExpressionAttributeNames: { '#SpecialStatus': 'Status' },
  IndexName: 'Artist-index',
  KeyConditionExpression: 'Artist = :ArtistName',
  ExpressionAttributeValues: {
    ':ArtistName': 'BlindGuadian',
    ':Track': 'Mirror Mirror'
  },
  FilterExpression: 'Track = :Track'
}
```

**Data** structure in DynamoDB's table:

```
{
'Artist' : 'Blind Guardian',
..
'Track': 'Mirror Mirror',
'Statistics' : [
   {
   'Sales': 42,
   'WrittenBy' : 'Kursch'
   }
]
}
```

Lets assume we want to filter out all entries from DB, by using Artist in KeyConditionExpression. We can achieve this by feeding Artist with :ArtistName. Now the question, ***how to retrieve records that I can filter upon WritenBy, which is nested in Statistics?***

To best of my knowledge, we are not able to use any other type but String, Number or Binary for purpose of making secondary indexes. I've been experimenting with Secondary Indexes and Sorting Keys as well but without luck.

I've tried documentClient.scan(), same story. Still no luck with accessing nested attributes in List (FilterExpression just won't accept it).

I am aware of possibility to filter result on "application" side, once the records are retrieved (by Artists for instance) but I am interested to filter it out in **FilterExpression**

Comment: `Statistics` is an object or an array?

Comment: Thank you for pointing out, Statistics should be an array of objects.

Comment: I'm still not clear about how you want to filter by "WritenBy". Could you describe it more in detail? An example would be perfect.

Comment: I should have use better example for data in DB, to be more clear. 

Lets say, we need to take all records from table for Artist = 'Blind Guardian' that were written by 'Kursch'. 
In my example up there (section "parameters I am feeding query with"), I am using Track for filtering records I'm interested in - and that works well, that scenario is covered. 

In new scenario lets take all DB records, which were  written by  'Kursch'. 

in case the design would be different, like "WrittenBy" wouldn't be in Statistics, I would make Secondary index for it, but that is not my case

Comment: Does `Statistics` array always have one object? I mean `FilterExpression` is only capable of checking nested values in a specific location, say `WrittenBy` key of the first object in `Statistics` array, etc.

Comment: Unfortunately Statistics can have and usually does have multiple objects. Even though, didn't know about possibly of accessing the specific object in List. Same with AWS GUI console, I wasn't aware that DynamoDB > Tables >Items does provide ability to "filter in List" for scan nor query. I see possibility to filter with attributes that are String, Number and Binary "typed".  Do I access specific object in the list same as in general practice via index? Say MyArray[recordIndex] ? Thanks

Comment: Here is the doc https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/Expressions.Attributes.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your problem correctly, you'd like to create a query that filters on the value of a complex attribute (in this case, a list of objects).

You **can** filter on the contents of a list by indexing into the list:

```
var params = {
    TableName: "myTable",
    FilterExpression: "Statistics[0].WrittenBy = :writtenBy",
    ExpressionAttributeValues: {
        ":writtenBy": 'Kursch'
    }
};
```

Of course, if you don't know the specific index, this wont really help you.

Alternatively, you could use the `CONTAINS` function to test if the object exists in your list.  The `CONTAINS` function will require *all* the attributes in the object to match the condition.  In this case, you'd need to provide Sales and WrittenBy, which probably doesn't solve your problem here.

The shape of your data is making your access pattern difficult to implement, but that is often the case with DDB.  You are asking DDB to support a query of a list of objects, where the object has a specific attribute with a specific value.  As you've seen, this is quote tricky to do.  As you know, getting the data model to correctly support your access patterns is critical to your success with DDB.  It can also be difficult to get right!

A couple of ideas that would make your access pattern easier to implement:

- Move `WrittenBy` out of the complex attribute and put it alongside the other top-level attributes.  This would allow you to use a simple `FilterExpression` on the `WrittenBy` attribute.
- If the `WrittenBy` attribute must stay within the Statistics list, make it stand alone (e.g. `[{writtenBy: Kursch}, {Sales: 42},...]`).  This way, you'd be able to use the `CONTAINS` keyword in your search.
- Create a secondary index with the `WrittenBy` field in either the PK or SK (whichever makes sense for your data model and access patterns).

Comment: thank you for your input and ideas you have mentioned